# Curvilinear coordinate system around body of revolution

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems

In *Boundary-Layer Theory* by Schlichting he gives the boundary-layer equations for a body of revolution according to the paper by Boltze$^1$. Unfortunately, this paper is in German. He apparently uses the following local curvilinear coordinate system to derive the boundary-layer equations:

[image: Fig. 11.6 from *Boundary-Layer Theory*]

I'm not specifically interested in deriving the boundary-layer equations for a body of revolution, however, I am working on a problem with a very similar geometry and am having trouble wrapping my head around the coordinate system.

**Question:**

For the locally orthogonal basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_x$, $\mathbf{e}_y$, and $\mathbf{e}_\theta$, what are the *gradient*, *divergence*, and *Laplacian* operators?

This is what I have tried:

$$x = \hat{x}$$
$$y = \hat{y}$$
$$r(x)\cos\theta = \hat{z}$$

where $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$ are coordinates in a Cartesian system with the same origin. Lamé's coefficients are then:

$$h_x = \left\vert\left(\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \hat{z}}{\partial x}\right)\right\vert = 1$$
$$h_y = \left\vert\left(\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial \hat{z}}{\partial y}\right)\right\vert = 1$$
$$h_\theta = \left\vert\left(\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial \hat{z}}{\partial \theta}\right)\right\vert = \left\vert r(x)\sin\theta\right\vert$$

With these coefficients it is straightforward to define the operators since this system is orthogonal (for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensors_in_curvilinear_coordinates#Grad.2C_curl.2C_div.2C_Laplacian) are the formulas).

I do not think that the results above are correct though since it compares to a local Cartesian system at each point. What are the correct transformations?

1. Boltze, Ernst. Grenzschichten an Rotationskorpern in Flussigkeiten mit kleiner Reibung. Georg-August-Universitat zu Gottingen., 1908.

**UPDATE:**

For any future Googlers, the correct transformation is: (based on Fig. 4 of @Floris's answer, $\xi$ is aligned with $U_\infty$ in the picture above)

$$\xi = x\cos\phi - y\sin\phi$$
$$\eta = -(r(\xi) + y\cos\phi + x\sin\phi)\sin\theta$$
$$\zeta = (r(\xi) + y\cos\phi + x\sin\phi)\cos\theta$$

where $\phi$ is the local angle of the body with respect to the axis of rotation, i.e. $\phi = arctan(\frac{dr}{dx})$. The paper by Boltze assumes this angle is small. The Jacobian is then:

$$J = r(\xi) + y\cos\phi + x\sin\phi$$

which is equivalent to Boltze's value for small $\phi$ and $y \ll r(\xi)$. And the Lamé coefficients are:

$$h_x = 1$$
$$h_y = 1$$
$$h_\theta = r(\xi) + y\cos\phi + x\sin\phi$$

Comment: Terrific that you updated with the "real" answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the original text at http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b2619178 (page 5 onwards). The relevant pages and key translation (each time I place the page before the translation - and I will repeat snapshots of equations in the translation where appropriate):

[image]

1) Contrary to the work by H Blasius, in this work we treat the problem of a body of revolution with its axis along the direction of the current. It is convenient to use the following coordinate system for the boundary layer (figure 2)

[image]

```
x = arc length along meridian curve
y = normal distance from the surface of the body
r = vertical distance to axis of rotation. r is a function of x and y, 
   but ultimately is only used as a way to describe the radius of the body of rotation.
```

2) We must transform the basic hydrodynamic equations into this framework. In the Cartesion framework, they are (in vector notation)

[image]

Transformation of the acceleration components $(\upsilon\nabla)\upsilon$ results in components like $u\frac{du}{dx}$, $v\frac{du}{dy}$ etc. as well as centrifugal forces like $\frac{u.v}{r}$ and $\frac{u^2}{r}$. Those components that appear in the expression for x components may be omitted since they are of order $s$ compared to other components like $u\frac{du}{cx}+v\frac{du}{dy} \sim 1$
[image]

The resulting shear force, according to figure 3, is

[image]

So

[image]

Thus, the following is left from the dynamic equation for the x direction:

[image]

Estimating the order of magnitude of the Y equation yields $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} \sim \frac{u^2}{r} \sim 1$

From this we conclude that $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ in the boundary layer differs from $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ in the potential flow field by an order of $s$, which we will neglect since we only preserve components $\sim 1$. Then we can use $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ that was computed in the potential flow field for the boundary layer. With that, the y equation has been fully exhausted for our use - it could only serve for more subtle calculations of $p$ in the boundary layer.

3. We want to write the continuity equation:

[image]

Where for a moment we consider $\xi, \eta$, and $\zeta$ as the rectangular coordinates. We then take the very general transformation
$$\xi=\xi(x,y,z); \eta=\eta(x,y,z); \zeta=\zeta(x,y,z);$$

By elementary computation, one finds the new continuity equation, in which :

[image]

The expression thus found is quite generally valid.

=====

I did the best I could. It doesn't answer your question exactly but I hope you can take it from here. Feel free to ask questions in the comments.

Comment: It was an interesting challenge... glad it worked for you!